# Windows git bash tries to resolve string as file when calling AWS CLI

Tags: windows, aws-cli, git-bash

I have a string parameter for AWS SSM CLI command that looks like a path to a file due to starting with a `/`. `/path/to/my/param`.

When I run the command on git bash it tries to find the file instead, no matter how I try to escape it:

`aws ssm get-parameter --name "/path/to/my/param"`

`aws ssm get-parameter --name '/path/to/my/param'`

`aws ssm get-parameter --name '\/path\/to\/my\/param'`

`An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetParameter operation: Invalid label format /Program Files/Git/path/to/my/param. A label name can't be prefixed with numbers, "ssm", or "aws" (case-insensitive). You can specify letters, numbers, and the following symbols: period (.), dash (-), or underscore (_).`

Even tried back-ticks, then I get a bash error

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name `/path/to/my/param`
```

Error: `bash: /path/to/my/param: No such file or directory`

If I do `echo /asd/asd` it actually outputs `/asd/asd`, so it also might be how the aws cli is treating the input.

Any ideas how to escape it?

Comment: if you are using windows, use powershell for this command

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to turn off a path conversion in MSYS2 for selected paths (see [Msys2 Porting](https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Porting), Filesystem namespaces section).

You can also disable it temporarily in the following way:

```
 MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="/aws" aws ssm get-parameter --name '/aws/path/to/my/param'
```

Comment: The documentation mentioned in this answer has moved to https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Porting/

Comment: According to the documentation : "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL is a ; delimited string each part of which is compared against the front part of each argument and if a match is found, that conversion is skipped."

Answer (score 7):

##### Edit:

After stumbling upon this issue once more, but this time for: `aws logs describe-log-groups --log-group-name-prefix ...`, I decided to try 'n' find a more sustainable solution.

I found an SO post that provided an explanation for the underlying problem as well as what I believe to be a better fix, i.e.:

```
MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 aws ...
```

This goes for any aws cli command suffering from this forward slash problem when being called from Git Bash on Windows.

Kudos of course go to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56034540

Seems like my first answer happens to work for `aws ssm get-parameter` because that part of the cli is a bit more forgiving in the sense that it returns the desired value, even when providing the leading space. *However*, upon further scrutiny of the returned value I noticed in retrospect that the name of the returned parameter also contains the leading space, making the solution of disabling path conversion - by far - the better option.

---

##### Original answer:

> In case anyone bumps into this issue in the future:
>
> I randomly managed to solve it while grasping at straws.
>
> The trick for me was to put a space before the first forward slash after surrounding the parameter name with double quotes, i.e.:
>
> ```
> aws ssm get-parameter --name " /path/to/my/param"
> ```
>
> (The GitHub issue that led me to try it out: https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/issues/196)

Comment: I ran into the same issue trying to run a command similar to the following:  `aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id SOMEID --paths '/some/path/'`.  The shell tries to be helpful and convert the path to some local computer path but instead it mangles the cloud path.  Adding `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` to the front of the `aws` command line worked.  Adding the space did not work for me.  Using a double slash at the front of the path also worked for me.

Comment: Also, without the fix, the `aws cloudfront create-invalidation` command shows a general message like the following:  `An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: Your request contains one or more invalid invalidation paths.`  I avoided the warning by adding an asterisk at the end of the original path, which hid the main problem and did not really solve the MinGW root issue.